# How do I convert a pages document to a word document without access to pages?

Tags: ms-office, pages, iwork

Suppose I didn't have access to a Mac with pages.  How can I convert a pages document to a word document using only a windows environment?  Is there a freeware converter available?

Comment: Right click on link and down the bottom of the menu that comes up it will say "Send to OneNote"
Press.

Comment: I could not find the Send to OneNote Press. I saved as/printed to a PDF, and then from AcrobatPro, save as a Microsoft Word document. Next, I make the request that the sender send as PDF, or MSWord, because my approach is way too clunky.

Comment: In which application did you print to PDF?

Answer (score 3):

Pages is free, so go get it if you can.

In addition to the iOS and macOS pages app, the iCloud version of Pages enable anyone on Linux, Windows and Mac to use a modern browser and edit/convert pages documents without needing local software.

This beta started rolling out to people that had brand new iCloud accounts in late July at https://beta.icloud.com and now Apple is [slowly rolling out](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/08/26/apple-limiting-access-to-iwork-for-icloud-beta-because-its-too/) the beta to [anyone that logs in](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/08/23/iwork-for-icloud-beta-now-open-to-everyone-with-an-apple-id/) to https://www.icloud.com

[image: iCloud]

The actual web apps are the same whether you enter through the beta URL or the normal URL and the only difference between the two is the treatment of the rest of the iCloud icons. The www url has linen and iOS 6 styling and the beta URL has iOS 7 styling without needing Mavericks or iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, there is. You can either do it online, with [**Zamzar**](http://www.zamzar.com), which requires and email address where you'll receive the converted files,  or download [**PagesConverter**](http://pagesconvert.sourceforge.net) which apparently does not keep the formatting and you need a .net framework.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you may not have [Pages](http://www.apple.com/iwork/pages/), there are other means to access it, as follows:

**Two viable solutions**:

- Why don't you email it to someone who has [Pages](http://www.apple.com/iwork/pages/) on a Mac******, and they can then save it for you as a Word document and email it back to you.
- Email it to yourself or put it on a usb stick, go to an Apple Store or equivalent, open it in [Pages](http://www.apple.com/iwork/pages/) on one of their Macs, save it as a Word document, and then email it back to yourself.

(****** That could well include someone here at Ask Different)

Answer (score 2):

Similiarly to bmike's answer, you could use the current version of iCloud ([www.icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com)) to upload your document in `.pages` format, and then download it in `.doc` format.

*Sorry, I have only access to the French version, so all menus are in French in the pictures, and I'm only guessing the English translations*.

- Login to iCloud
- Click the Pages icon

[image: pages icon]

- In the top right corner, click the dented wheel icon, and select "Load a document"

[image: wheel menu]

- Once the document is uploaded, it will appear in the center of the window, right-click it and select "Download the document"

[image: right click menu]

- You will be prompted to choose a format

[image]

Comment: No need to apologise, its good to learn some French, Merci....

Comment: Nice screen shots of the beta app. We're hopefully always tolerant of non-native speakers - feel free to ping me and the mod team if you ever run into grief about that.

Comment: This a public beta (http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9241871/Apple_quietly_launches_iWork_for_iCloud_public_beta), so I don't think there is anything wrong with these screenshots.